# When writing an ExpressJS app, why is the "new" keyword not used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express

So I noticed as I learn ExpressJS, most of the tutorials/etc. I see start off

```
var express = require('express');
.
.
.
var app = express();
```

what actually is going on with storing the output of the call to the `express` function to `app`? Why isn't the `new` keyword there, as it looks like an instantiation to me?

Comment: its how they designed their interface.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
var express = require('express');
```

The express module returns to you a **factory function**.  A factory function is a regular function that you call like a regular function and when you call it, it creates and returns an object.

It's not a constructor directly (which is why you don't use `new` on it). That was a design choice by the creators of the Express library.  They chose not to expose a regular constructor to the `app` object directly.

You can see the exported `express` function in the code right [here in the source repository](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L37).  Internally, they call it `createApplication`.  If you look at the code, you will see that it's actually not a plain object.  It's a mixin (an object that combines the functions and instance data of several objects) and they chose to implement the creation of that mixin object using a factory function.

FYI, here's part of the code (this `createApplication` function is what gets returned from loading the `express` module):

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;

function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  // expose the prototype that will get set on requests
  app.request = Object.create(req, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  // expose the prototype that will get set on responses
  app.response = Object.create(res, {
    app: { configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, value: app }
  })

  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: then in that case, is that's what loaded with the `require('express')`? What about the other modules I might load like `var http = require('http')`?

Comment: @user11039951 - Each module decides what it wants to export and you find out how to use the module in its documentation or by looking at its code.  Some modules (like `express`) export a function (that also happens to have custom properties).  Others (like `http`) export an object as you can see in the http module source [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L53).

Comment: @user11039951 - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community here at stackoverflow by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to "accept" this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It's how the Express team designed Express.JS - it's a different kind of constructor. One kind of constructor uses `this`:

```
function NewItem(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}
```

The other kind returns an object - this is the kind Express uses:

```
function newItem() {
    return {
        prop: "defaultProp"
    }
}
```

It's just a different way, and it's how Express designed their framework.

Comment: Additionally, using `new` just makes an object based on the function's `this` if the function does not return anything. Prototyping aside, there is no other notable difference.